# Record has not been saved, but auto-incremented id in database has been incremented

Tags: hibernate

I have two tables to store answers and HTML template of a form. Table answers has foreign key whih refers to primary key in html_templates table. There is a problem when I try to add a record to answer table.

```
//session opened
    Answers answers = new Answers();
    answers.setAnswer("answer...");
    //there is a record in getHtmlTemplates with 4 as an id
    answers.setHtmlTemplates(getHtmlTemplates(4));
    session.save(answers);
```

Program executes without any warrings, but there is no record in DB (MySql). When I am adding a record to `answers` manually, the id is incremented by more than one. Actually when all operations are within transaction a record is added. What happened? It looks like DB database has deleted this record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that you are not committing the transaction. For auto-increment columns like MySQL uses, the `save` method causes a dummy record to be inserted so that Hibernate can retrieve the new ID value (notice that `save` returns an object, which is the new ID). MySQL has now marked that value as being used, which is why it looks like the ID has "jumped" when you manually insert.

Comment: You are probably right. But I was taking about situation I don't even start any transaction. I only opened a session and saved an new object in session, then I invoked session.flush(). Didn't work. As I said when I used transaction all works, but do I need to start a transaction? It works this way with a table without foreign key, so transaction must be started (and committed) when there will be probably more than one SQL query execution (retrieving primary key from object from database)?

Comment: Hibernate does everything in a transaction. In your example above, a transaction is started implicitly, but you never `commit` it -- hence, no data.